# Fetch the slot value used for a previous intent(method) and use it in current method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am working on building an alexa skill where the requirement is to fetch the value for previous slot..

```
User:  Alexa,create an appointment
Alexa: please state the subject for appointment
User : subject is {subject}
Alexa: on which day?
User : {Day}
Alexa : Appointment has been created with {subject} on {day}
```

Final method should fetch  values from previous slots(subject and date) and create an appointment. 
So far i'm able to fetch slot value for current intent...but i would like to fetch the slot value for previous intent and use it in the current method.

***Example**

```
protected SpeechletResponse method1(Intent intent,Session session)throws 
Exception{
    SpeechletResponse response=null;

Map<String, Slot> slots =  intent.getSlots();
Slot example = slots.get(SampleSlot);
String value=example.getValue().toString();
String output="something";

response = SpeechletResponseHelper.getSpeechletResponse(output, reprompt, 
true);
    return response;
}

protected SpeechletResponse method2(Intent intent,Session session)throws 
Exception{
SpeechletResponse response=null;

****How to fetch the slot value used for method1 and use it in method2? ****

response = SpeechletResponseHelper.getSpeechletResponse(xxxx, reprompt, 
true);
return response;
}
```

Is this possible?If so how can i do it?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used sessions to achieve my query like this....

```
Map<String, Slot> slots =  intent.getSlots();
Slot example = slots.get(SampleSlot);
session.setAttributes(Sample_String);
session.getAttributes(SampleSessionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use `session.setAttribute()` and `session.getAttribute()` as mentioned here - https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java/blob/master/src/com/amazon/speech/speechlet/Session.java

Answer (score 0):

like Amit said, you should be able to use `session.setAttribute`, however, if for some reason you want to keep something that might not be accepted by the `session.setAttribute` you can always have a **field variable** that is always available, until the session closes of course, once the session closes it's all gone without a database.

```
String output;

    protected SpeechletResponse method1(Intent intent,Session session)throws 
    Exception{
        SpeechletResponse response=null;

    Map<String, Slot> slots =  intent.getSlots();
    Slot example = slots.get(SampleSlot);
    String value=example.getValue().toString();
    output="something";

    response = SpeechletResponseHelper.getSpeechletResponse(output, reprompt, 
    true);
        return response;
    }

    protected SpeechletResponse method2(Intent intent,Session session)throws 
    Exception{
    SpeechletResponse response=null;

    ****How to fetch the slot value used for method1 and use it in method2? ****

    response = SpeechletResponseHelper.getSpeechletResponse(output, reprompt, 
    true);
    return response;
    }
```

All I did there was initialize the string variable `output` in a higher scope(outside the method) which makes it available for any other methods.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my query i got it sorted out using sessions!!